# How to design a Component that should be accessed from both C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, components

My application has subsystems (components/dll) in unmanaged C++ and C#. Now I am going to create a new subsystem (dll) for a specific purpose which should have classes and methods . These classes and methods can be used by other subsystems C++ or C#.

How can I design a component which can be used either by C++ and C#.

Comment: Given the stated constraints, COM would be the most obvious choice.

Comment: Do you mean C++/CLI or just plain unadulterated C++?

Comment: Here C++ refers unmanaged C++

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities.

If you are ready to use managed C++ you can create your components directly in C# and then reuse them. Managed C++ is not the most convenient language but perfectly ok for creating intermediate layer for .net components used in c++ code.

Or you can make your components COM-visible indeed, as suggested in comments.

I would probably choose the first approach because it doesn't require components registration.